# oracle log path for invalid user

Tags: sql, oracle, logging

When login credentials fail, Oracle gives an error in SQL terminal :

> invalid username/password; logon denied

I need help to know where does Oracle keep this log. I need this log to generate suspicious login.

Comment: It rather depends on whether your system has AUDIT SESSION enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle provides a built-in functionality to track failed logins as part of the **standard audit trail**.

[Once the audit trail is enabled](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50521), the following command can be used to turn on auditing of failed logins (it needs to be executed as `SYSDBA`) :

```
audit create session whenever not successful;
```

Failed logins will be reported in table `dba_audit_trail`.

Comment: Well i had tried this earlier and it did work. I want to know weather oracle keep this log in a directory or folder rather than a table where i have to execute query.